# Example of convergence under $\|\cdot\|_2$, but not pointwise.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and $f$ a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Assume that $\|f_n-f\|_2\rightarrow 0$. Does it follow that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for some $x\in [0,1]$? Give a proof or counterexample. Also, can NOT use Lebesgue here.

$\text{Proof}$

Let $f(x)=0$ and $I_{n,k}(x)=\{\chi_{\left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right]}:n\in \mathbb{N}, k=0,...,2^n\}$ where $\chi_{\left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right]}$ is defined as
[\begin{cases} 
      f_{n,k}(x) & \text{if}\space x\in \left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right] \\
      0 & \text{if}\space x\notin \left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right] \\ 
   \end{cases}
 and $f_{n,k}(x)$ defined as 
\begin{cases} 
      (2^{n+1})x + (2-2k) & \text{if}\space x\in \left[ \frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{2k-1}{2^{n+1}} \right] \\
      -(2^{n+1})x + 2k & \text{if}\space x\in \left[ \frac{2k-1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{k}{2^n} \right] \\ 
   \end{cases}

Each "bump" is a triangle over the interval $\left[\frac{k-1}{2^n},\frac{k}{2^n}\right]$ with height $1$, so the area would be $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.
Hence, $\large\int^{\frac{k-1}{2^n}}_{\frac{k}{2^n}}f_{n,k}(x)dx=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ and, therefore, we have that 
$$ \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\int^{1}_{0}I_{n,k}(x)dx=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\sum^{2^n}_{k=1}\int^{\frac{k-1}{2^n}}_{\frac{k}{2^n}}f_{n,k}(x)dx=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\sum^{2^n}_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}0=0 $$
Hence, the sequence converges under $\|\cdot\|_2$, but for any $x\in [0,1]$ we can choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that
$$ |f_{N,k}(x)|>\frac{1}{2} $$
Therefore, $I_{n,k}(x)$ converges no-where to $f(x)$.

Can anyone please check if my reasoning is correct? I know I'm probably not very convincing at the end since I do not know what value to make $N$, but I know that the interval can be divided up enough so that it isn't $0$. I'm also not sure if I have shown convergence under $\|\cdot\|_2$ here either.

Comment: In your statement of your question, when you say "for some $x \in [0, 1]$", do you mean "for **all** $x \in [0, 1]$"?

Comment: It is for some $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: In  your last line you have $\lim_{n\to \infty}A(n)=0$ where $A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac {1}{2^{n+1}}$ but this is $false$ because $A(n)=1-2^{-(n+1)}$. Furthermore what you are interested in is whether $\int_0^1 (\sum_{k=1}^nI_k)^2dx $ goes to $0.$

Comment: BTW you can use \text {....} between dollar-signs or between double-dollar signs, around material (like the word "if") that should be un-Latexed... E.g .\text { if }.  You can also use \, and \; and \quad to insert  various sizes  of extra space. E.g. in a displayed line I like to write \; \text  { if }\;  for the word "if"